# Dimensional model or Relational model for data warehouse?

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a pretty trivial questions in data warehouse,

I know we use Dimensional data model to construct data marts and use Relational data model in staging area.

What data model technique we use to store data in central data warehouse? Can we use both? Which is most commonly used? We have RDBMS for relational database model, what is the database used for dimensional modelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What data model technique [do] we use to store data in central data warehouse?

The Dimensional data model.  The reason for having a data mart or a data warehouse is to answer time and other dimensional related queries.

> We have RDBMS for [the] relational database model, what is the database used for dimensional modelling?

For small data marts (< 1 million rows), a relational database works for dimensional models.  Dimensions have a relationship with the fact tables (packages, SKUs, etc.)

For large data warehouses (> 10 billion rows), you'll get better performance if you use a database designed for [online analytical processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing). In the 1990's, I managed a DB2 data warehouse that added 2 million fact table rows per day, and it worked well enough.

For medium size data warehouses, it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks! I was going through this article which suggests we can use Relational data model for data warehouse (For large data as well)
Link: https://cours.etsmtl.ca/mti820/public_docs/lectures/WhichDWArchitectureIsMostSuccessful.pdf
Thoughts?

Comment: For Hub-Spoke Architecture, we have normalized relational data warehouse. I guess it is based on the business needs we select either dimensional or relational..

Comment: @Nikhil: The star model is one of the many data models for a data warehouse.  If you build a relational data model, you're just duplicating the operational database.  Now, companies have built relational databases to consolidate hierarchical operational data, but that's not a data mart or a data warehouse.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

Comment: You're getting denormalised and relational mixed up. If we only consider building these things in a relational database, then yes, your staging database would probably match the source, which would probably be _normalised_, and the data warehouse would probably be dimensional, which is _denormalised_. Relational implies a relational database, which can have a normalised or denormalised data model. A relational database doesn't have a relational data model.